# Nodejs vs C++ performance for simple mathematic

Tags: c++, node.js

I made the same program to test performance on Nodejs and C++ on Mac OS X.

First in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    clock_t t1, t2;

    cout << "Initializing\n";

    t1 = clock();

    double m = 0;
    for (double i = 0; i != 10000000000; ++i) {
        m = i * -1 + i;
    }

    t2 = clock();
    float diff = (((float) t2 - (float) t1) / 1000000.0F) * 1000;

    cout << "Finalizing with " << diff << "ms\n";
}
```

Second in Nodejs:

```
console.log("Initializing");

t1 = Date.now();

var m = 0;

for (var i = 0; i != 10000000000; i++) {
    m = i * -1 + i;
}

t2 = Date.now();
var diff = t2 - t1;
console.log("Finalizing with %dms", diff);
```

The result was 50000ms for C++ and 22000 for Nodejs.

Why Nodejs is faster for that kind of operation?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Switching double and using long int, it gave me 22000ms, like Nodejs.

Comment: 1. Post your compiler settings. 2. Know how your code is optimized.  3. Understand your data types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the code for 2 languages is not equivalent. In C++ you used `double` and in javascript variable was optimized to be integers (although their type is `Number` which in general case is floating-point type). And, of course, floating point operations are always longer than operations on integers.

Try to replace `double` with `int` or better with `long` in the C++ version. This will ensure you have integers in both versions.

If you do that please consider posting results for us to see the difference. T

Comment: `int` will not do, since it is usually 32 bits even on 64 bit systems.

Comment: @Krumelur, thanks. And thanks, sasha.sochka, I understood you the first time.

Comment: JavaScript's `Number` values [are doubles](http://es5.github.io/#x4.3.19), unless [bitwise operators](http://es5.github.io/#x11.10) are used.

Comment: My reputation, doesn't allow up-button =)

Answer (score 2):

It is quite difficult to measure performance straight off using this type of code. Both the C++ compiler and the V8 JITter uses different types of optimization of the generated native code.

A few things to look out for:

- The code `i != 10000000000` is dangerous. Always compare doubles using inequalities (`<>`) rather than equalities (`==`, `!=`).
- There is no need to use floating point at all, use the `long long` type instead. The thing is, NodeJS may actually do this optimization automatically, since it is dynamically typed.
- You don't actually use `m` anywhere. If you compile with  `g++ -O3`, the compiler may actually optimize away the whole loop (try it!).

Comment: Thanks, @Krumelur. I tryed it before you answer and now I tryed with -03, there is no difference to me. Why is dangerous != since I'm using ++i?

Comment: This page sums it up pretty good: http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/